# Buffy. The First imitates dead people

Tags: comics, vampire, buffy-the-vampire-slayer

For those who have read Buffy comics knows that

> Warren is still alive.

In the last season of Buffy (s07) The First (of all evil) imitates different dead people, because that is the only thing he can do. At one point he imitates

> Warren, though according to the comics, he was still alive. Amy the witch had saved him.

So how could The First  have taken his appearances?

Comment: Though I think I have read that season 8,9,10 are canon. And it's in the 8 one Warren appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implication (from the [Buffy Wikia](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Warren_Mears)) is that she "resurrected" Warren. We know that the First can imitate those who've [died and come back](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19993/how-did-the-first-evil-take-the-shape-of-buffy?rq=1) since it imitates Buffy at one point.

> *The real Warren, however, returned months after the destruction of
>   Sunnydale. **Seconds after he was killed by Willow, Amy used her magic
>   to resurrect Warren and keep him "alive" despite his lack of skin.** He
>   was the one who gave Amy the idea of cursing Willow in order to become
>   him, and he bore a considerable grudge against both Willow (for
>   flaying him) and Buffy (for ruining all of his plans)*

In the comic serial ([Buffy Season 8 #4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1595823107)), Warren notes that his "*human life*" ended when Willow attacked him. Since his sole means of survival is Amy's magic, it's probable that he's classed as undead rather than magically alive.

[image]