# Why didn't The First ever become Willow?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

Why didn't The First Evil ever take the form of Willow?

She technically died in season 2, episode Halloween. She died and became her costume as a ghost, so the first could have appeared as Willow too.

Especially in the first episode of season 7 when it took the form of all the previous Big Bads, Warren, Glory, Adam, the Mayor, Drucila, and the Master. It should of appeared as Willow as well, in my opinion.

Comment: Willow didn't die. She was dressed as a ghost for Halloween so when the spell was cast, that's what she _became_, she didn't die and leave a body behind, her body became _ghost like_

Comment: @BinaryWorrier Spot on.  Should be an answer, IMHO.

Comment: I forget - did it ever become Buffy? She died in Season 1....

Comment: Vampire Willow's image was an option, if she just had to exist for a time (after her death) in our universe.

Comment: @RDFozz yes she died twice actually. Once drowned by the Master, and the second time to save dawn in the 5th season.

Comment: @Flitoangel - Sigh - not sure how I forgot that second death when I responded. Kind of significant :-)

Comment: @RDFozz Yes, it did take Buffy's form. See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19993/how-did-the-first-evil-take-the-shape-of-buffy/20024

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [script](http://www.buffyworld.com/buffy/scripts/018_scri.html) makes it pretty clear that she's not actually dead, merely enchanted along with the other people wearing the magical outfits. Note the artful quote marks.

> EXT. SIDEWALK IN FRONT OF MRS. PARKER'S HOUSE - CONT. - NIGHT
>
> ON WILLOW'S SHEET-CLAD FORM
>
> As the **"ghost"** Willow, dressed in her rocker babe outfit, sits up -
> emerging from her **"dead"** body, which remains unmoving on the ground.
>
> **WILLOW:** Oh. Oh my God...
>
> She stands, sees her BOOTS submerged in the
> sheet.
>
> **WILLOW:** *I'm a... I'm a real ghost -*

Answer (score 11):

**Willow didn't die**

She was dressed as a ghost for Halloween so when the spell was cast, that's what she became.
She didn't die, her "spirit" left her body, in a form of astral projection. I assume her body was still alive but in a catatonic state.

Comment: She did leave her body. I just watched the episode. It was left on a porch covered in the ghost costume. Her ghost self was dressed in her clothes under the costume.

Comment: Well observed mate, but we don't know if he corporeal body kept breathing and her "spirit" just became un-tethered.

Comment: Right :) I was just thinking about it, because the term ghost actually means the spirit of someone who has died.. confusing lol

Comment: By the same logic, Xander became a soldier, but he didn't go through basic training, the transition was immediate & instant.